# Download an Entire Website in C#

Tags: c#, web, screen-scraping, screen, download

Forgive my ignorance on the subject

I am using

```
 string p="http://" + Textbox2.text;
 string r= textBox3.Text;
 System.Net.WebClient webclient=new
 System.Net.Webclient();
 webclient.DownloadFile(p,r);
```

to download a webpage. Can you please help me with enhancing the code so that it downloads the entire website. Tried using HTML Screen Scraping but it returns me only the href links of the index.html files. How do i proceed ahead

Thanks

Comment: Did you get your problem resolved?

Answer (score 10):

Scraping a website is actually a lot of work, with a lot of corner cases.

Invoke [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) instead.  The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/index.html) explains how to use the "[recursive retrieval](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Download.html#Recursive-Download)" options.

Answer (score 9):

```
 protected string GetWebString(string url)
    {
        string appURL = url;
        HttpWebRequest wrWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(appURL) as HttpWebRequest;
        HttpWebResponse hwrWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wrWebRequest.GetResponse();

        StreamReader srResponseReader = new StreamReader(hwrWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string strResponseData = srResponseReader.ReadToEnd();
        srResponseReader.Close();
        return strResponseData;
    }
```

This puts the webpage into a string from the supplied URL.

You can then use REGEX to parse through the string.

This little piece gets specific links out of craigslist and adds them to an arraylist...Modify to your purpose.

```
 protected ArrayList GetListings(int pages)
    {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            string page = GetWebString("http://albany.craigslist.org/bik/");

            MatchCollection listingMatches = Regex.Matches(page, "(<p><a href=\")(?<LINK>/.+/.+[.]html)(\">)(?<TITLE>.*)(-</a>)");
            foreach (Match m in listingMatches)
            {
                list.Add("http://albany.craigslist.org" + m.Groups["LINK"].Value.ToString());
            }
            return list;
    }
```

Comment: +1, also remember to parse all text files (html, css) as them can have links to other resources