# How to save WebBrowser page in wp7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, browser

I have WebBrowser control in my WP7 app

I want to save the page in HTML or PDF or JPG file in isolated memory for read it later.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202(v=VS.95).aspx):

```
WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += (o, e) => DoSomethingWithResult(e.Result);
downloader.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(yourWebBrowser.Source.ToString()));

private void DoSomethingWithResult(string result)
{
    //...
}
```

Of course, you need to check `e.Error` and so on... I left that out for the sake of brevity.

In order to download the *entire page*, not just the HTML, you should look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091758/download-an-entire-website-in-c-sharp). Be warned, it probably isn't as simple as you think.

**EDIT:** in order to show the HTML you saved using the above method, call [WebBrowser.NavigateToString(result)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring.aspx).
You can find an example [in this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/16/displaying-html-content-in-windows-phone-7.aspx).

Comment: you said you wanted the HTML, PDF or JPG. This gives you the HTML. Edit your question and be more exact if you need help with *showing* a locally saved html file.

Comment: yes but i want complete HTML that's contains images and ... for offline view

Comment: @L.B note the *or*. I've edited the answer with a link to an SO question that deals with *downloading the entire page*.

Comment: @Downvoter, I'm pretty confident that I answered the question as posed by the OP, and I'm trying to accommodate what they are adding in the comments, so take a second to reconsider your vote.

Comment: is there any way to save it to JPG file?

Comment: @L.B in fact, it is possible, [as this blog post proves](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/16/displaying-html-content-in-windows-phone-7.aspx), by using the `WebBrowser.NavigateToString()` method as shown [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring.aspx).

Comment: @L.B No, I'm sorry. I have no idea how to save it as a JPG. I was responding to your comment about how downloading the HTML would be unsuitable - as my links show, it is possible to display the downloaded html later. And the SO question I linked contains information about how to download the entire page (images, etc) - the difficulty would be about how to display the page *exactly* as it first appeared, but using the MSDN technique it is at least possible to preserve CSS and JS, leaving only the images as a problem, which could probably be worked around.

Comment: @L.B I respect your decision to downvote (while disagreeing, of course, on the grounds that your reasoning is incorrect), but I wanted to give you the chance to see that using `WebClient` to download the HTML **is** a reasonable suggestion. I promise I won't bother you with further mentions...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6126/discussion-between-codesparkle-and-l-b)