# How can i download a website content to a string?

Tags: c#

I tried this and i want that the source content of the website will be download to a string:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        WebClient client;
        string url;
        string[] Search(string SearchParameter);


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            url = "http://chatroll.com/rotternet";
            client = new WebClient();




            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://chatroll.com/rotternet");
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        static void DownloadDataCompleted(object sender,
           DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
        {



        }


        public string SearchForText(string SearchParameter)
        {
            client.DownloadDataCompleted += DownloadDataCompleted;
            client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(url));
            return SearchParameter;
        }
```

I want to use WebClient and downloaddataasync and in the end to have the website source content in a string.

Comment: Why do you have both a `webBrowser1` and a `client`?

Comment: "I want to sue WebClient .." :)

Comment: There is a difference between website and web page, and in this case it's very significant. You are downloading a single page. It will not have any linked resources (images, css, javascript, frames) nor you will download any linked pages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download an Entire Website in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091758/download-an-entire-website-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `WebRequest`:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

You can easily call the code from within another thread, or use background worer - that will make your UI responsive while retrieving data.

Answer (score 7):

No need for async, really:

```
var result = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url)
```

If you don't want to block your UI, you can put the above in a BackgroundWorker.  The reason I suggest this rather than the Async methods is because it is dramatically simpler to use, and because I suspect you are just going to stick this string into the UI somewhere anyway (where BackgroundWorker will make your life easier).

Answer (score 6):

If you are using .Net 4.5,

```
public async void Downloader()
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        string page = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://chatroll.com/rotternet");
    }
}
```

For 3.5 or 4.0

```
public void Downloader()
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            string page = e.Result;
        };
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://chatroll.com/rotternet"));
    }
}
```